# What is the need for direct and fanout exchanges?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

As per my understanding, all the functionality or use-cases of direct and fanout exchanges can be achieved using topic exchange. Topic exchange supports superset of functionality. So the question is, why does RabbitMQ have direct and fanout exchanges? Are there any use-cases that can be achieved using direct/fanout exchange but not with topic exchange?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say it's a matter of **simplification**. *If* all you need is, say, a topology where each specific routing key maps 1:1 with a queue (round robin distribution of tasks between multiple workers within the same application is an example cited in the *RabbitMQ* doc), then *Direct exchanges* may be easier to use and work with, and all you need. That's not to say you couldn't accomplish the same thing using *Topic Exchanges* (you could).

Similarly, with *Fanout exchanges*, if you have a situation that calls for the simply broadcasting of messages, you may find a *Fanout exchange* is easier to work with. Again, that's not to say you couldn't accomplish the same thing using *Topic Exchanges* (you could).

I generally use *Topic exchanges* exclusively, because I value the flexibility they provide. As an application expands, they can handle a greater variety of use cases within the same exchange, whereas that may not be the case with the other two types. Thus I can avoid the potential for having to change the topology midstream as an application grows.

As the *RabbitMQ* doc states about *Topic exchanges*:

> Topic exchanges have a very broad set of use cases. Whenever a problem
>   involves multiple consumers/applications that selectively choose which
>   type of messages they want to receive, the use of topic exchanges
>   should be considered.

For more information about these concepts, including illustrations, this page has quite a bit of info:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html

Comment: Can you elaborate on "easier"? From what I learnt about RabbitMQ, the differences among these exchange types are just the binding key and routing key. Besides, how about performance? Are fanout exchanges faster because they do not check the routing keys of the messages?

Answer (score 3):

You could replace the functionality of direct and fanout with a topic exchange, but you could also implement a big "Animal" class and don't bother implementing the "cat" and "dog" ones…

The different exchange types offer specificity according to your needs. You could do broadcast with the topic exchange, but then you need to force every client to know about the meaning of `#` and require them to use that routing key when binding; or just use a fanout exchange.

On the implementation side, implementing a topic exchange is a bit more complex, require a data structure that asks for more book-keeping than a plain fanout or direct exchange.